# How can I make chromium run on startup using Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 - Model B, with Raspbian jessie operation system.
Im trying to open "chromium" on startup.

i wrote a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.google.com
exit 0
```

**I can run the script manually and it works** perfect.
I read about a lot of various ways to run this script on startup.
I have tried:
adding this line `@reboot path/to/my/script` to `crontab -e` file with no success.
Also i have tried to edit `/etc/rc.local` file by adding this line:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
  /home/pi/Desktop/script1.sh&   <-------- THIS LINE 
fi
exit 0
```

I have checked that the script is **executable** and rc.local too:

- rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi script1.sh
- rwxr-xr-x 1 root root rc.local

I can see script1.sh tesk on my Task Manger (it runs as root) but nothing happen.

The default user is Pi and i log as a Pi user and not as root, maybe this is the problem?
Can someone explain me what is the problom and why i can see the script only in the Task Manager? what should i do ? 
TNX!

**UPDATE**
i have changed the rc.local to be like:

```
!/bin/sh -e
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
  su - pi -c "/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.google.com &"
fi
exit 0
```

**still does not work for me :|**

Comment: In your rc.local, you seem to be missing a space between your command name and the `&`.  Outside of this it looks like you have the right idea.   You could try `printf "running..."; /home/pi/Desktop/script1.sh || printf "FAILED %d"  "$?" &` to get some more info (to double check you've modified the right rc.local, etc...)

Comment: i can see the script on the Task manager also it has a pid, but i cant see it (the browser window)  :| maybe it works on background or something...any ideas??? :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small hack...

I added this line `@lxterminal` to the end of this file:

```
nano .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

It will auto-start terminal on boot.

Then I edited `$ sudo nano .bashrc` file.
At the end of the file, I added my path to my script.

```
./home/pi/Desktop/script.sh
```

It means that:

1. The terminal will open every time you boot your Raspberry Pi (first command).
2. Every time that terminal runs, my script will run also (second command)

It does work for me.
TNX for the help :)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the verified answer on this question...
[Running Shell Script after boot on Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578852/running-shell-script-after-boot-on-raspberry-pi?rq=1)

Looks like you need to run the script as the user `pi`.

`su - pi -c "/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.google.com &"`

EDIT: I missed the `&` at the end of the command.

Comment: if i add those lines i can not see the script on the Task manger.. :|

Comment: Yes you right, id i run it manually i see user is -Pi, and in the command line the user is Root.

Comment: Sorry i missed the & at the end.  Likely chromium was being forced shut immediately because it wasn't being run in the background.  Try the new script.

Comment: The only thing left i can think of is that this has to do with how rc.local is run by the system.

Comment: The thing is that i can see the script in the terminal and the user is root, after adding your lines i cant see the script anymore :| tried to add this line: root ALL=(pi) NOPASSWD: ALL,on the visudo file.... with no change :| any ideas ?

Comment: You can't edit comments -_-.  What i'm getting at is it feels like the script is executing correctly, even running as the correct user, but i'm wondering if the way the system runs rc.local is making chromium run in a way that doesn't allow it to bind to the screen correctly.  So the application is actually running but didn't know how to display itself in the GUI environment.  Just a hunch but i'm out of ideas besides that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the shell script path directly to *`~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`* (not to ~/.bashrc) works better.

Namely it does not execute the command every terminal session (including ssh).

Try this in the autostart file instead:

```
@sh /home/pi/Desktop/script.sh &
```