# Starting Reaper on startup Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to get the application Reaper to start as soon as my Pi has turned on. I have tried many methods to try and achieve this that didn't work including:

Firstly I used Cron to Schedule a Program

```
'@/usr/local/bin/reaper &'
```

Secondly, I went to the autostart folder and pasted in the location of the application:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart 
@/usr/local/bin/reaper
```

Thirdly I created a new file in the autostart directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/display.desktop

// And added:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Reaper
Exec=reaper
```

After trying all of these options I didn't know what to try next, did I uses these methods correctly? Are there any other efficient ways someone could recommend please?

Answer (score 1):

After running the ./install_reaper.sh script and setting a desktop integration (there is an option to either install (choice 'i') or add the desktop integration without install 'a').

I then tried your final suggestion and it worked, the only difference I made was the following:

sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/reaper.desktop

[Desktop Entry]

Name=Reaper

Exec=reaper

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a cron-job that needs to be run at startup is

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/reaper &
```

Beware that the `@reboot` is what tells cron to run the command at each startup

PS. I'm not sure about the `&` at the end, since you won't need to run reaper as a background job in cron

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have added '@reboot /usr/local/bin/reaper &' with and without the '&' and it doesn't work for me. I have also tried the path to a reaper file, this doesn't work either. Do I need to add the extension to the end of this path above? I also read elsewhere that with a GUI this is not the best method to use?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't know that reaper was a GUI software, I've checked later. Cron is definitely not suited for GUI autostart, a .destkop file in the /etc/xdg/autostart folder or in the .config/autostart one could be a better solution indeed, or just [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489508/how-can-i-make-chromium-run-on-startup-using-raspberry-pi-3) is something similar